# Can’t fetch a record ID field in SQL with GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group, having

I have a table with structure

```
CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER  
QUOTE_ID    INTEGER  
VALIDFROM   DATE
```

Customer can have multiple quotes.  I need to get list of Quote IDs where VALIDFROM DATE is MAX  for each customer.  Query below returns list of quotes grouped by customers and MAX VALIDFROM DATE but how can I find out QUOTE_ID of this record? Including QUOTE_ID in group clause produces wrong results

```
SELECT q.custid, max(q.validfrom)  
  FROM QUOTE Q  
 GROUP 
    BY q.CUSTID
```

Please help!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name FireBird 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that helps:

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM quote q
  JOIN(SELECT q.custid, max(q.validfrom)  
         FROM quote q
        GROUP 
           BY q.custid   
       ) P
     ON q.custid = p.custid
    AND q.validfrom = p.validfrom;
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to include `QUOTE_ID` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Just simply do this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, QUOTE_ID, MAX(VALIDFROM)
FROM QUOTE 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

Or, if you only need `QUOTE_ID` grouped by customers, then you can use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT QUOTE_ID
FROM QUOTE 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
HAVING MAX(VALIDFROM)
```

**EDIT - 1:**

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) pointed out, I've changed my query in the following way:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, QUOTE_ID, MAX(VALIDFROM)
FROM QUOTE 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, QUOTE_ID
```

Comment: Your first statement is invalid SQL and will be rejected by all DBMS except MySQL (which prefers to return random data instead). The second one is also invalid because `HAVING MAX(q.VALIDFROM)` is not a valid expression